# Не могу найти нужный "class" в коде элемента

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хочу контролировать цифры на бинансе но не могу найти "class" с этими цифрами[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://p2p.binance.com/ru-UA/trade/Wise/USDT?fiat=USD'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.64'}

full_page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

convert = soup.find("div", {"class":"css-16jkuzw"})
print(convert)
```

Сайт: https://p2p.binance.com/ru-UA/trade/Wise/USDT?fiat=USD

Comment: используйте `selenium`

Comment: сложновато для меня